# Retrieving CheckedItems from an UltraComboEditor

Tags: c#, infragistics

I'm using an UltraComboEditor(Infragistics) and setting its DataSource to a list of User object that I've created.

```
cboHiddenAreaUser.DataSource = _users.Where(user => !user.IsInactive).OrderBy(user => user.FullName).ToList();
```

With a standard WinForms ComboBox, I'm able to cast a SelectedItem as User object and get the data I need. What's the best approach to retrieving the checked User objects selected by the user? I'm getting an error stating that I "Cannot cast expression of type 'Infragistics.Win.CheckValueListItemsCollection' to type 'List'".

```
var selectedUsers = (List<User>)cboHiddenAreaUser.CheckedItems;
```

Comment: You could probably loop through the checked items collection and add those to a List<User>.  Pretty sure you can cast an individual item from the combo to a User, just can't cast the whole collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would retrieve each user this way:

```
foreach (Infragistics.Win.ValueListItem item in ultraComboEditor1.CheckedItems)
{
    User u = (User) item.ListObject;
}
```

The `ListObject` property stores the underlying bound instance for each item.  Then you could just build your own list to return the "checked" users.